# DOMXPath slow to parse url's?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to parse several url's just to see if a certain div id exists. First I tried using simplehtmldom but it was very slow, so the latest I've tried is domxpath. It still takes roughly the same amount of time for the page to load. I'm pretty new to all this so I don't know what kind of limitations there are to parsing. You will notice in my code I'm using unset to try and clear the memory after it loops through each time. It didn't make any difference on performance but I just left it in because it wasn't affecting anything, and I'm not sure if it's necessary to have that in there or not?

So..my question is, from taking a look at my code below, is there anything I could do to parse these url's any faster? Also, is parsing 50 url's for what I'm wanting to do too much to ask? Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
    require_once("include.all.php");
    if ( !class_exists( "Standings" ) ) {
        Class Standings {
            public static function Status( $url ) {
                $html = file_get_contents($url);        
                $doc = new DOMDocument;
                $previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
                $doc->Loadhtml($html);
                libxml_clear_errors();
                libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value);
                $element = $doc->getElementById( 'cams_view_top' );
                if ( $element == null ) {
                    echo "<img src='images/offline.fw.png'/>";
                    unset( $doc,$html );
                } else {
                    echo "<img src='images/online.fw.png'/>"; 
                    unset( $doc,$html );
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried your script parsing only one url to measure that time? It may be that one specific url is taking too long to be fetched and processed. Are those documents well formed?. Also, your description is clear, but the idea doesn't seem to make much of a sense, whay parsing that many urls/pages to find that div?

Comment: How long is "very long"? Which part is taking long (fetching the websites, parsing them, querying them)? Did you consider parallelizing the execution?